# Has Anyone Motorized Ocean Explorer Set #42064?

Tags: technic, power-functions, remote-control

[image]

Me gustaría saber si tiene alguien <strike>monitorizado</strike> motorized el LEGO Technic - Explorador oceánico 42064 y si es así si alguien podría pasarme las instrucciones?

Muchas gracias!

***Google Text Translated:***

I would like to know if anyone has *motorized* the LEGO Technic - Ocean Explorer 42064, and if so, could someone show me how?

Thank you!

***Editor's note:***
Translation errors aside, I'm using this *Youtube* video [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RDH9UZ_Ag6s) as a reference to what I think the OP is referring to when he means "Motorized" in hopes that more people will at least understand what he's looking for, and focus on getting the answer he wants.

[image]

- Based off what the darn thing does, is it possible to motorized these functions?

[image]

- The main vessel itself has wheels to make it go forward and backward.

[image]

[image]

- It has a steerable moving rudder.

[image]

There are more functions like a moveable Crane, Helicopter and Submarine.  Not sure how many things he wants to hook up to a motor, so I kept focused on the moving ship.

Comment: You might get better results if you try and provide an English version of your question. SE sites tend to be English only unless they are specifically for another language.

Comment: The OP made a mistake in their posting and used the spanish word for “monitoring” instead of the word for “motorizing”. I have corrected the english translation.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a video of 42064 as RC model but no building instructions
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A7P5WEdphSE